# JaxB rename class with duplicate name

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xsd, jaxb

I have to use a schema which contains the following snippet where the name `object` is duplicated.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="param_object_type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="object" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="object" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Jaxb was originally happy to import this, but would fail to compile the sources since the Object class was declared twice.

I added `globalBindings` option `localScoping="toplevel"` and this now leads to the following compile time error:

`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: A class/interface with the same name "jaxb.Object" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.`

So I tried adding a custom binding to rename one of the objects, `jaxb:class` and `jaxb:property`. Both produce the same error.

If it helps, here is my bindings file:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false" fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty="true" choiceContentProperty="true" localScoping="toplevel"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings  schemaLocation="../xsd/NodeSchema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="/xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name='param_object_type']/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='object']">
            <jaxb:class name="object2"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

How can I make sure that one of these instances gets renamed and the other is left intact?

Comment: Have you solved this problem? If you have solve it, How have you done?

Comment: Fixed using the answer below. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right complex type .. missing close tag for `xs:element`

**XSD**

```
<xs:complexType name="param_object_type">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="object" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="object" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

**Bindings**

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:schema//xs:complexType[@name='param_object_type']//xs:sequence//xs:element[@name='object']//xs:complexType//xs:sequence//xs:element[@name='object']">
    <jxb:class name="object2" />
</jxb:bindings>
```

**ParamObjectType.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "param_object_type", propOrder = {
    "object"
})
public class ParamObjectType
    implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 2L;
    protected List<ParamObjectType.Object> object;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the object property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the object property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getObject().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link ParamObjectType.Object }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<ParamObjectType.Object> getObject() {
        if (object == null) {
            object = new ArrayList<ParamObjectType.Object>();
        }
        return this.object;
    }


    /**
     * <p>Classe Java per anonymous complex type.
     * 
     * <p>Il seguente frammento di schema specifica il contenuto previsto contenuto in questa classe.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType>
     *   &lt;complexContent>
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *       &lt;sequence>
     *         &lt;element name="object" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
     *       &lt;/sequence>
     *     &lt;/restriction>
     *   &lt;/complexContent>
     * &lt;/complexType>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "object"
    })
    public static class Object
        implements Serializable
    {

        private final static long serialVersionUID = 2L;
        @XmlElementRef(name = "object", type = ParamObjectType.Object.Object2 .class, required = false)
        protected List<ParamObjectType.Object.Object2> object;

        /**
         * Gets the value of the object property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
         * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
         * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
         * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the object property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
         * <pre>
         *    getObject().add(newItem);
         * </pre>
         * 
         * 
         * <p>
         * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
         * {@link ParamObjectType.Object.Object2 }
         * 
         * 
         */
        public List<ParamObjectType.Object.Object2> getObject() {
            if (object == null) {
                object = new ArrayList<ParamObjectType.Object.Object2>();
            }
            return this.object;
        }

        public static class Object2
            extends JAXBElement<java.lang.Object>
        {

            protected final static QName NAME = new QName("", "object");

            public Object2(java.lang.Object value) {
                super(NAME, ((Class) java.lang.Object.class), ParamObjectType.Object.class, value);
            }

            public Object2() {
                super(NAME, ((Class) java.lang.Object.class), ParamObjectType.Object.class, null);
            }

        }

    }

}
```